# error: Package requirements (libssh2) were not met

Tags: 14.04, package-management, monodevelop

I have troubles installing [monodevelop](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop). I was trying to follow [this](http://www.davidloo.com/?p=479) tutorial but I had an error when hitting this command `./configure --profile=stable`. Here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting

[image]

I don't know how to resolve this dependence, please help. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install `libssh2` by running `sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev`.

Comment: For building a package from source, it will probably be necessary to install `libssh2-1-dev` rather than just the runtime library package `libssh2-1`

Comment: I did it. It says that the package is already installed and the newest version, but still don't work

Comment: Thanks! when I installed the `-dev` version it worked. thanks again :)

Comment: Should have thought of that...